# Why is UIImageView on UIButton reappearing on touch?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I am setting the UIImageView on UIButton to an image, but hiding that image if something is loading. I am then adding a UIActivityIndicatorView to where the image view was. However, when I touch the button Title, the image view is suddenly appearing without changing the hidden property. It doesn't have anything to do with the selector/target I've added to the button because I've commented that out.

Button Creation:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitle:buttonTitles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:buttonTitles[i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Adding Indicator View in Button Category:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator startAnimating];
indicator.frame = self.imageView.frame;
[self addSubview:indicator];
self.imageView.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Change the title of your question, this is not a UIImageView is only UIImage

Comment: Not sure what you mean... the imageView property on UIButton is a UIImageView

Comment: Yes, but the image is what you need to disappear.

Try this:

`UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator startAnimating];
indicator.frame = self.imageView.frame;
[self addSubview:indicator];
[button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to hide the image is to set `nil` for the `UIControlStateNormal` state instead. Replace

```
self.imageView.hidden = YES;
```

with

```
[self setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: how can i remove the indicator view and get the picture back then?

Comment: is subclassing UIButton an option?